# IPHONE: Testing for iPhone OS 2.+ and 3.+

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an application developed for iPhone OS 3.+. This application uses in-app purchase.

I would like to release a version now, that it is compatible with 2.+.

Obviously I will have to use that techniques described by Apple that tests for the presence of the frameworks I am using from 3.0 and make alternative code for 2.0, without using those 3.0 frameworks.

my question is: my iPhone is updated to 3.0. How do I test to see for 2.0? Do I need an iPhone that is already using 2.0 or is there anything I can do to simulate this?

thanks for any answer

Comment: Are you listening, Apple?  I think it's fair comment and passes the "relevant to programmers" test to ask this question, whether it stays open or is closed.

Comment: Apple acts in an arbitrary fashion and kicks programmers in the butt constantly. There are a series of limitations that is disgusting. An iPhone for the programmer should have multiboot, allowing the programmer to install two versions of the OS and choose between them on boot.

Comment: Yes, they "arbitrarily" decided to not allow multi-boot. It was just a boolean variable and they were like NAH and set it from "true" to "false" just to be jerks.

Comment: everything is possible in programming. Yes Apple does arbitrary things constantly kicking the programmers in the butt.

Comment: given unlimited resources, sure, everything is possible. However, Apple needs to decide where to spend its limited engineering time, talent, and money. Obviously, dual-boot capability, which would be of use to far less than 1% of their users, is not high on their list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need a 2.x device. Optionally, you can installed an older version of Xcode on Leopard, and test using the sim, but still, you should always test on a device.

Comment: You don't need an older version of Xcode. When you installed the latest SDK there was an option to install support for 2.x OS versions. However this is unselected by default. You may need to reinstall...

Comment: Yes I know. My Xcode on Snow Leopard has all versions from 2.0 up. My problem is to test a hybrid 2.0/3.0 application...

Comment: another problem is that itunes does not let you downgrade the OS on your iphone...

Comment: Xcode on Snow Leopard will let you build for 2.x *devices*, but not the simulator.

Comment: Yes I know. My problem is not build, is test.

Comment: Exactly, which is why you'll either need to use Leopard or an actual 2.x device.